# What can I do for preprocessing image BMP before using PCA by MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, pca, image-preprocessing

I have BMP images .I want to preprocessing it with compatible way that can handle by using PCA for features extracting .

Answer (score 0):

You can start by putting each image into a column and then call PCA on that.  Use `imread` to read in the images and `reshape` to change each image into a column vector.

Comment: Here is a slide deck which talks more about it.  The stuff related to images starts on slide 16.  It looks like you're also supposed to subtract the mean from each image (slide 13).

http://people.ciirc.cvut.cz/~hlavac/TeachPresEn/11ImageProc/15PCA.pdf